# What can we say about behavior of $\sum_{p |n} \frac{p}{\log p}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers

We want to estimate $\displaystyle \sum_{p|n} \frac{\log p}{p}$. It's well known that $\displaystyle \sum_{p \le n} \frac{\log p}{ p} = \log n + O(1)$.

Of course the former series should be smaller than second one, but what's the behavior? I think it should be $\log \log n$ (like instead of $n$ we should consider $\log n$, because of number of elements in this sum). Also I thought about Moebius function, but it doesn't work here. Any hints?

Comment: You can maximize the number of terms by taking $n$ as a primorial.

Comment: @ajotatxe then I'll find the upper bound?

Comment: Your question doesn't make **sense**,  with the PNT we can estimate $\sum_{n \le x}\sum_{p|n}{\frac{p}{\log p}}$ but not $\sum_{p|n}{\frac{p}{\log p}}$ which oscillates a lot (try with $n=2^m$ and $n+a$ prime). Also $$\sum_{p \le x} 1 \sim \sum_{k \le x} \frac1{\log k} \implies\qquad \sum_{p \le x} \frac{p}{\log p} \sim \sum_{k \le x} \frac{k}{\log^2 k} \sim\frac1{\log^2 x}\sum_{k \le x} k\sim \frac{x^2}{2\log^2 x}$$

Comment: I suppose it should be log p / p, and not p / log p.

Comment: It doesn't change my comment that we can estimate $\sum_{n \le x}\sum_{p|n}\frac{\log p}{p}$ but $\sum_{p|n}\frac{\log p}{p}$ oscillates @gnasher729

Comment: @gnasher729 Edited , sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$:
$$\displaystyle \frac{\log n}{n} \leq \sum_{\substack{p|n \\ \text{p prime}}} \frac{\log p}{p}$$
And we have equality iff $n$ is prime.

Let $n = \displaystyle{\small \prod_{\substack{p \leq m \\ \text{p premier}}} {\normalsize p}}$. Then :
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle\sum_{\substack{p|n \\ \text{p prime}}} \frac{\log p}{p} & = & \displaystyle\sum_{\substack{p \leq m \\ \text{p prime}}} \frac{\log p}{p} \\ \\
 & = & \log m + O(1) \\ \\
 & = & \log\Big((1+o(1))\log(n)\Big)\,\, , \quad (\text{prime number theorem})\end{array}$$

Then we have for all $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$:
$$\displaystyle \frac{\log n}{n} \leq \sum_{\substack{p|n \\ \text{p prime}}} \frac{\log p}{p} \leq \log\Big((1+o(1))\log n\Big)$$

You can see that $\displaystyle\sum_{\substack{p|n \\ \text{p prime}}} \frac{\log p}{p}$ haven't an equivalent whene $n \to +\infty$.